# SQL Server: restore a database in an active/passive two-node cluster

Tags: sql-server

I have a MS SQL Server (2014 enterprise) that runs in an active/passive two-node cluster.

I need to restore the database to a new version and I would like to keep the clustering configuration.

I know how to restore a MS SQL server on my single laptop for development, but what are the steps for database restore in an active/passive cluster?

Comment: for DBA question use: http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

clustering works at hardware level,so there are no special steps involved in restoring a database ,whatever may be clustering setup..

You will need to take extra care only when you are doing this in HA like always on ,mirroring...

EDIT:
if your database is part of availability group,then follow this.https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82548/restoring-a-sql-server-2012-database-in-high-availability

Comment: Yes, I do have Always On.

Answer (score 1):

If no replication is configured then it should be the same steps as if you are backing up/restoring from your laptop.

Comment: I believe I have replication.

Comment: Then your active/publisher only needs to be restored. You can script the replication, however, unless you are scaling out wildly then it may not be worth the time. I would restore, then simply create another snapshot and let the subscribers restart their pulls.